# project moving point onto a line

Tags: graphics, manipulate, animation

The following code displays three solutions to the logistic ODE with an animated points that follow the solutions.. My goal is to project the solutions on to a vertical phase line. I need to be able to create a phase line of exactly length as the x-axis and have the projected solutions move appropriately. As you can see my projections do not lie on a fixed length copy of the x-axis. Additionally, I want to plot fixed points at x=0 and x=1 and be able to set any color I want to the fixed and moving points. The phase line needs to be closer to the tx-plot as well.

Finally, I'd like to be able vary the parameter r and the initial value x0 in the solution formula (see Initialization code)

Please help relieve my frustration.

```
Manipulate[

 y1[t_] = y[t, 0.2, 2];
 y2[t_] = y[t, 0.2, 0.1];
 y3[t_] = y[t, 0.2, -0.01];

 If[s == 20, s = 0];

 GraphicsRow[{
   Plot[{y1[t], y2[t], y3[t], 0, 1}, {t, 0, 20}, 
    ImageSize -> {600, 400}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {-1, 2}}, 
    PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Black}, {Thick, Black}, {Thick, 
       Black}, {Thick, Black, Dashed}, {Thick, Black, Dashed}}, 
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 16}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
    FrameLabel -> {t, x}, RotateLabel -> False, AspectRatio -> 0.75, 
    PlotRangePadding -> 0.1, 
    Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], Red, 
      Point[{{s, y1[s]}, {s, y2[s]}, {s, y3[s]} }]}],

   Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Red, 
     Point[{{0, y1[s]}, {0, y2[s]}, {0, y3[s]} }]}]}
  ],

 {{s, 0, "FLOW"}, 0, 20, .01, ControlType -> Trigger, 
  AnimationRate -> 3, 
  AppearanceElements -> {"StepLeftButton", "StepRightButton", 
    "PlayPauseButton", "ResetButton", "FasterSlowerButtons"}},

 FrameLabel -> 
  Style["One dimensional flow associated with logistic equation", 16, 
   FontFamily -> "Helv"],

 Initialization -> (y[t_, r_, x0_] := 1/(1 + (1/x0 - 1) Exp[-r t]))
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please format your question - the markdown help is just around the corner: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/formatting

Comment: Should I use Dingus to convert to HTML?

Comment: @Stephen I already did it for you. Please read Yves' link

Comment: @Yves - What is the easiest way to convert my Mathematica code to Markdown formatting?

Comment: @Stephen The second and third sections of Yves' link explain code blocks and inline code.  Are they not helpful?

Comment: Indent four spaces - it is all in the link (or peek at the edited question).

Comment: Related answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43155/streamplot-for-bifurcation-diagram/43174#43174

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 y1[t_, r_] := y[t, r, 2];
 y2[t_, r_] := y[t, r, 0.1];
 y3[t_, r_] := y[t, r, -0.01];
 If[s == 20, s = 0];
 Plot[{y1[t, r], y2[t, r], y3[t, r], 0, 1}, {t, 0, 20},
  Frame -> True, Axes -> False,
  PlotRangePadding -> {{.1, 2}, {.1, .1}},
  Epilog -> {
    PointSize[0.02], Red, 
    Point[{{s, y1[s, r]}, {s, y2[s, r]}, {s, y3[s, r]}}],
    Black, Line[{{21, -2}, {21, 3}}], Blue,
    Point[{{21, y1[s, r]}, {21, y2[s, r]}, {21, y3[s, r]}}]}],
 {{s, 0, "FLOW"}, 0, 20, .01},
 {{r, 0, "r"}, 0, 1, .01},
 Initialization -> (y[t_, r_, x0_] := 1/(1 + (1/x0 - 1) Exp[-r t]))]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @bellsarius :-)

Comment: @bellsarius: I want to place a fixed circle at {21,0} and a point at {21,1} of color Green. I cannot do this within Epilog.

Comment: @bellsarius I want to plot fixed points at {21,0} and {21,1} and be able to set different colors to all of the points - both fixed & moving.

Comment: @Stephen Use the Epilog to plot the points and a `ColorSetter` control to choose the colors

Comment: The file you proposed does not export to a cdf properly. Also, I don't want a ColorSetter control; rather, I just want to fix the colors of the fixed points other than Blue.

Comment: @Stephen A few things: 1) I haven't proposed any "file" 2) You never mentioned exporting to a CDF in the question 3) Change the "Blue" in my code for whatever you want 4) This isn't a "do it for me" kind of site.