# A problem in bifurcation diagram

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, differential-equations, graphics, nonlinear

I have the following problem

```
A = 10; B = -2; tab = 
Table[{sol, points} = 
Reap@NDSolveValue[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == 
   B*x[t] - R*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - A*y[t], 
   Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == B*y[t] - R*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - A*x[t], 
   x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1, 
   WhenEvent[Re[x'[t]] > 0, If[t > 0.1, Sow[y[t]]]]}, {x, y}, {t, 
  0, 50}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]; {R, #} & /@ 
Union[Flatten[points], SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < .02 &)], {R, 0, 
20, 0.01}];
ListPlot[Re@Flatten[tab, 1], AspectRatio -> .75/GoldenRatio, 
ImageSize -> Large, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], 
AxesLabel -> {R, x}]
```

[image]

The output is very strange, is there a way to make it look like a proper bifurcation diagram?

Comment: What kind of plot were you expecting?  The variation in the y-axis is quite small, if you include `PlotRange->{0,All}` it will appear insignificant, as in @GregoryRut's answer below.

Comment: @ChrisK I was trying to plot a bifurcation diagram which would look like [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaSSB.png), not the same of course, but with an overall shape like a usual bifurcation diagram. The parameters are all flexible, also the conditions. I am just varying different parameters/conditions to arrive at something similar to the above mentioned shape. It has to be for the parameter $R$.

Comment: Could be that your model has no bifurcations in the range of R you've studied.  I've NDSolved the equations for a few R in your range and it seems the bifurcation diagram you get is basically correct.

Comment: @ChrisK, I have posted an answer to my post, probably you can have a look at the code there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it might be related with `WorkingPrecision`. 
I tried this (`Table`->`ParallelTable`, added `WorkingPrecision->25`, changed `{R, 0,20, 0.01}` to  `{R, 0,20, 1/100}`)

```
A = 10; B = -2; tab = 
 ParallelTable[{sol, points} = 
   Reap@NDSolveValue[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == 
       B*x[t] - R*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - A*y[t], 
      Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == B*y[t] - R*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - A*x[t], 
      x[0] == 1, y[0] == -1, 
      WhenEvent[Re[x'[t]] > 0, If[t > 0.1, Sow[y[t]]]]}, {x, y}, {t, 
      0, 50}, MaxSteps -> Infinity, 
     WorkingPrecision -> 25]; {R, #} & /@ 
   Union[Flatten[points], SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < .02 &)], {R, 0, 
   20, 1/100}];
ListPlot[Re@Flatten[tab, 1], AspectRatio -> .75/GoldenRatio, 
 ImageSize -> Large, PlotStyle -> PointSize[Tiny], 
 AxesLabel -> {R, x}]
```

and got

[image]

Comment: thanks yes it looks better than mine, however I thought it would be possible to arrive at something similar to [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaSSB.png), as I pointed out to ChrisK.

Comment: Is the argument in theplot from the link is the same as `R` in your code? Are there any other parameters that need to be altered?

Comment: No it is not the same. the `R` in my code is a different parameter than the link. The link is actually from another post I was trying to implement for my system, available at [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96004/plotting-a-bifurcation-diagram/96047). All parameters and conditions can be altered to any degree if it is possible by any means to arrive at a plot similar to the one in the link. I have tried several alterations but didn't work.

Comment: The bifurcation occurs for `R`. So the x-axis will be `R`

Answer (score 0):

I think in the following plot, the 'bifurcation' diagram appears but it is very complicated. (Note: It was taking too long for $A=10$, so I set $A=1$ in the following code, also the initial conditions changed)

```
B = -2; A = 1;
s = ParametricNDSolveValue[{Sqrt[-1]*x'[t] == 
 B*x[t] - R*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - A*y[t], x[0] == 1, 
Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == B*y[t] - R*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - A*x[t], 
y[0] == 0}, {x, y}, {t, 0, 100}, {R}];
```

and

```
coll = {};
Table[pp = 
ParametricPlot[Re@Through[s[a][t]], {t, 0, 100}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}];
pts = pp[[1, 1]];
AppendTo[
coll, {a, #[[1]]} & /@ 
pts[[First@Cases[pp[[1]], Point[x__] :> x, -1]]]];, {a, 0.0, 5, 
0.01}];
lp = ListPlot[Join @@ coll, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> Red];
Manipulate[
Column[{ParametricPlot[Re@Through[s[par][t]], {t, 0, 100}, 
PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}}, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", 
MeshFunctions -> (#2 &), Mesh -> {{0.}}, 
MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize[0.01]}, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {"x[t]", "y[t]"}], 
Show[lp, Graphics[{Gray, Line[{{par, 0}, {par, 4}}]}]]}], {par, 
0.0, 5, 0.01}]
```

It is a bifurcation diagram in red, but its hard to visualize a point where the stable solution starts to become unstable, i.e., the bifurcation. There are several points or windows in this range which exhibit modes where the solutions could be stable? Beyond these windows on either side, the system seems chaotic.