# Plotting a Hopf bifurcation diagram

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

Can anyone guide me on how to obtain the Hopf Bifurcation diagram? I am very new to this topic.I am trying to plot a Hopf bifurcation diagram for the system with bifurcation parameter `α` with the following given values:

```
α = 2.438571114; β = 0.2; δ = 2.3; γ = 0.7;
```

My system is

```
{x'[t] == x[t](1 - x[t]) + x[t]y[t], 
 y'[t] == y[t](δ - (β y[t])/x[t]) - (α y[t])/(γ + y[t])}
```

Can anyone guide me on how to obtain a Hopf bifurcation diagram. Plot should have parameter α on x-axis and xy on y-axis

Comment: http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/HopfBifurcationsInANonlinearTwoDimensionalAutonomousSystem/

Comment: Please show what you've tried to show where you are stuck.

Comment: Closely related question: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13277/mathematica-code-for-bifurcation-diagram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you give parameter values where there is a limit cycle to get started with?  The parameters given result in a blowup.

```
α = 2.438571114; β = 0.2; δ = 2.3; γ = 0.7;
tmax = 100;

sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == x[t] (1 - x[t]) + x[t] y[t], 
  y'[t] == y[t] (δ - (β y[t])/x[t]) - (α y[t])/(γ + y[t]),
  x[0] == 1, y[0] == 1}, {x, y}, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]];

(* NDSolve::nderr: Error test failure at t == 15.34966818880772`;
  unable to continue. *)

Plot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol], {t, 0, 15.349}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]