# Bifurcation diagram for coupled nonlinear equations

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, nonlinear

My code is the following

```
Subscript[ϵ, 1] = 0.5;
Subscript[ϵ, 0] = 2;
ω = 2;
γ = 1;

sol = NDSolve[{Sqrt[-1]*
     x'[t] == ω*x[t] - γ*x[t]*Abs[x[t]]^2 - 
     Subscript[ϵ, 0]*y[t] - 
     Subscript[ϵ, 1]*Abs[y[t]]^2*x[t], 
   Sqrt[-1]*y'[t] == ω*y[t] - γ*y[t]*Abs[y[t]]^2 - 
     Subscript[ϵ, 0]*x[t] - 
     Subscript[ϵ, 1]*Abs[x[t]]^2*y[t], x[0] == 2, 
   y[0] == 0}, {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}]

{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]]], {t, 0, 100}]
```

It gives me only a frame for the plot but no plot, I don't know what is missing?. I actually want to draw a bifurcation diagram. 
I would highly appreciate if someone could additionally help with any other fancy way to draw a bifurcation behavior corresponding to this set of nonlinear coupled equations. 
Any help is much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: try `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Re@({x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]])], {t, 0, 100}]` or `ParametricPlot[Evaluate[ReIm@({x[t], y[t]} /. sol[[1]])], {t, 0, 100}]`

Comment: @kglr: Thanks it works. So essentially the first means only plot for real modes, and the second for both imaginary and real ones? Secondly, I was wondering if there is another way to plot the bifurcation behavior. would be really nice to understand what is actually happening. Thanks once again!

Comment: AtoZ, right. Re bifurcation diagrams using Mathematica see [this post by Mark McClure](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13313/125).

Comment: You should avoid using [`Subscript`](https://wolfr.am/vxtW3QtE) while defining symbols (variables). `Subscript[x, 1]` is not a symbol, but a composite expression where `Subscript` is an operator without built-in meaning. You expect to do $x_1=2$ but you are actually doing `Set[Subscript[x, 1], 2]` which is to assign a [`DownValues`](https://wolfr.am/vxtQt6LX) to the operator `Subscript` and not an `OwnValues` to an indexed `x` as you may intend. Read how to [properly define indexed variables here](https://wolfr.am/vxtT6JDX)

Comment: What variables do you want on the x- and y-axes of your bifurcation diagram?

Comment: @kglr I think that post by Mark McClure is more for discrete-time difference equations vs. differential equations as here...

Comment: @ChrisK yes that post by Mark McClure doesn't seem to be of much help. I want to see bifurcation behavior between γ which is the local strength vs energy (ω), x-axis will be ω and y-axis will be γ. Then this Subscript[ϵ, 1] will have an effect on the bifurcation which I want to see. Actually for stationary case the energy is (ω-w) and for that I have the bifurcation diagram which is just straight lines, but this bifurcation diagram will be interesting.. I am actually very new to Mathematica so unable to plot this.