# Find a stable 3-cycle of the sine map

Tags: difference-equations

I am trying to find  an stable 3-cycle for the sine map $g(x) = a \sin(\pi x)$ but I do not know exactly how to use mathematica to do so. Is there anyone familiar with this?

$x$ lies as before between 0 and 1 but the real parameter $a$ is positive but not greater than 1. Use the bifurcation diagram to locate the 3-cycle

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! There are a lot of posts on this site with answers explaining how to make bifurcation diagrams. Maybe start by searching for those and seeing if one of them helps you! [Here's one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13277/mathematica-code-for-bifurcation-diagram).

Comment: is there any other ways to do this more simply?

Answer (score 10):

This is how you define the function $g$ in *Mathematica*:

```
g[a_, x_] = a*Sin[π*x];
```

Making a color-plot of the function $g(g(g(x)))-x$ in the $a$-$x$ plane and indicating the zero-contours, we see the lobes of 3-cycles:

```
DensityPlot[g[a, g[a, g[a, x]]] - x, {a, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

Now we know where they all are, find a 3-cycle for a specific value of $a$:

```
With[{a = 0.95},
  x3 = x /. FindRoot[g[a, g[a, g[a, x]]] == x, {x, 0.2}];
  {{x3, g[a, x3], g[a, g[a, x3]], g[a, g[a, g[a, x3]]]}, 
   Abs[D[g[a, g[a, g[a, x]]], x]] /. x -> x3}]
```

> {{0.201558, 0.562152, 0.931948, 0.201558}, 4.06318}

Oops, this is an unstable 3-cycle as the derivative (last number) is larger than 1 in magnitude (thanks @march!). Try again:

```
With[{a = 0.94},
  x3 = x /. FindRoot[g[a, g[a, g[a, x]]] == x, {x, 0.15}];
  {{x3, g[a, x3], g[a, g[a, x3]], g[a, g[a, g[a, x3]]]}, 
   Abs[D[g[a, g[a, g[a, x]]], x]] /. x -> x3}]
```

> {{0.176489, 0.494893, 0.939879, 0.176489}, 0.345007}

This time it worked: we found a stable 3-cycle $0.176489, 0.494893, 0.939879$ at $a=0.94$.

Let's make a new plot where the cycle contours are only shown in the stable regions (i.e., only stable 3-cycles):

```
g3[a_, x_] = Nest[g[a, #] &, x, 3];
dg3[a_, x_] = D[g3[a, x], x];
DensityPlot[g3[a, x] - x, {a, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> Red, 
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  RegionFunction -> Function[{a, x, f}, Abs[dg3[a, x]] <= 1]]
```

[image]

Zooming in on one of the regions of stable 3-cycles:

[image]

The two black dots that mark the limits of the stable 3-cycle band are found with

```
Q1 = {a, x} /. FindRoot[{g3[a, x] == x, dg3[a, x] == 1}, {{a, 0.94}, {x, 0.5}}]
```

> {0.937818, 0.5152}

```
Q2 = {a, x} /. FindRoot[{g3[a, x] == x, dg3[a, x] == -1}, {{a, 0.94}, {x, 0.5}}]
```

> {0.942488, 0.485444}

The region of stable 3-cycles is therefore $a\in[0.937818, 0.942488]$.

Comment: I'm a little suspicious of your results here.  I made the bifurcation diagram, and I think that 0.2 is in the region where there is exactly one fixed point. Furthermore the 3-cycles occupy a *region* in `a`-space. Something like $0.938 < a < 0.942$, roughly.

Comment: @march you're right I didn't do a stability analysis, so what I wrote is too simplistic.

Comment: This is cool! I wasn’t aware that you could do this kind of analysis.

Comment: @Roman The colored background looks awesome, but I guess the only relevant bits are the zero contours, right?  I also like the unstable 3-cycle on the other side of the stable one!

Comment: @ChrisK yes the colors are just to be fancy, they're otherwise useless. You could do a `ContourPlot` instead of a `DensityPlot` to go easier on the eyes if you want.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a more brute-force approach to generate the whole bifurcation diagram using [`Nest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nest.html) and [`NestList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NestList.html).

```
g[x_] := a*Sin[π*x];

warmup = 200; (* # warmup iterations *)
pts = 200; (* # points to save *)
ic = 0.01; (* initial condition *)

ListPlot[Flatten[Table[
    Transpose[{Table[a, pts], 
    NestList[g, Nest[g, ic, warmup], pts - 1]}],
  {a, 0, 1, 0.001}], 1],
PlotStyle -> {Black, Opacity[0.2], PointSize[0.001]},
AxesLabel -> {a, x}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

[As @Roman found](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/197467/6358), the 3-cycle looks like it lives around `a=0.94`.  We can zoom in to see it better:

```
warmup = 500;
pts = 500;

ListPlot[Flatten[Table[
    Transpose[{Table[a, pts], 
    NestList[g, Nest[g, ic, warmup], pts - 1]}],
{a, 0.93, 0.95, 0.00001}], 1], 
PlotStyle -> {Black, Opacity[0.1], PointSize[0.001]},
AxesLabel -> {a, x}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]